# How to set route in Laravel for paypal autoreturn url with "rm" variable set to 2

Tags: laravel, paypal

If "rm" variable is set to 2, PayPal documentation says:

"The buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment variables are included."

How to set route in Laravel for this situation, and read all data sent from PayPal ? (I want to check that it is POST request)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Laravel packed:  paypal/rest-api-sdk-php, here you go an easy tutorial to start:

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-with-laravel54example.html